# How to get every possible combination fixed length string

Tags: python, math

I have a string that is xxYxx where x is a letter a-z and Y is a number 0-9. How do I get all possible combinations of this. For example:

aa1b
ab2r
xy9p

There are all valid possibilities.

Comment: 1-10, not 0-9? Also: your examples do not match your template `xxYxx`, they only have one letter after the digit.

Comment: Do you want to get all possibilities, or do you want to filter strings to accept only a "schema" of string ?

Comment: I want to get all possibilities. And you are right it's 0-9 sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
import itertools
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def all_strings():
    numbers = map(str, range(1, 11))
    return map(''.join, itertools.product(alphabet, alphabet, numbers, alphabet))
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(itertools.islice(all_strings(), 100))
['aa1a', 'aa1b', 'aa1c', 'aa1d', 'aa1e', 'aa1f', 'aa1g', 'aa1h', 'aa1i', 'aa1j',
 'aa1k', 'aa1l', 'aa1m', 'aa1n', 'aa1o', 'aa1p', 'aa1q', 'aa1r', 'aa1s', 'aa1t',
 'aa1u', 'aa1v', 'aa1w', 'aa1x', 'aa1y', 'aa1z', 'aa2a', 'aa2b', 'aa2c', 'aa2d',
 'aa2e', 'aa2f', 'aa2g', 'aa2h', 'aa2i', 'aa2j', 'aa2k', 'aa2l', 'aa2m', 'aa2n',
 'aa2o', 'aa2p', 'aa2q', 'aa2r', 'aa2s', 'aa2t', 'aa2u', 'aa2v', 'aa2w', 'aa2x',
 'aa2y', 'aa2z', 'aa3a', 'aa3b', 'aa3c', 'aa3d', 'aa3e', 'aa3f', 'aa3g', 'aa3h',
 'aa3i', 'aa3j', 'aa3k', 'aa3l', 'aa3m', 'aa3n', 'aa3o', 'aa3p', 'aa3q', 'aa3r',
 'aa3s', 'aa3t', 'aa3u', 'aa3v', 'aa3w', 'aa3x', 'aa3y', 'aa3z', 'aa4a', 'aa4b',
 'aa4c', 'aa4d', 'aa4e', 'aa4f', 'aa4g', 'aa4h', 'aa4i', 'aa4j', 'aa4k', 'aa4l',
 'aa4m', 'aa4n', 'aa4o', 'aa4p', 'aa4q', 'aa4r', 'aa4s', 'aa4t', 'aa4u', 'aa4v']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this some kind of Regex you need ? Or a generator for an Array ?
In case of Regex i would do something like :

```
/^[a-z]{1,}([0-9]|10){1}[a-z]{1,}$/
```

[Test in Regexr](https://regexr.com/4vb80)

Otherwise, just iterate all values ?

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code that should give an idea of what you need to do.

```
listOfStrings = [];
for x in [a ... z]
    for Y in [1 ... 10]
        string xYString = xxYxx;
        listOfStrings.append(xyString);
//listOfStrings now contains all desired combinations of xxYxx
```